# how to prevent inserting NULL values and raising exception instead

Tags: peewee

After running this code, the data will be inserted into the database. when I check the database, I find a row added with values: int_field=0 and other="" (empty string)

My question is how to throw exception in case of Null/empty insert.

```
from datetime import datetime

db = pw.MySQLDatabase('tests', user = 'root', password = 'root', host = 'localhost', port = 3306)

class Model(pw.Model):
name = pw.CharField()
created_at = pw.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now())
other = pw.CharField(null = False)
int_field = pw.IntegerField(null = False)

class Meta:
    database = db
    db_table = 'nmodel'
Model.create_table()
Model.create(name = "tests")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a MySQL `strict_mode` issue, you should enable it in peewee Database Instance Like below.

Add this (`sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'`) to the constrcutor call:

```
db=pw.MySQLDatabase('database_name', user='user_name', password='user_psswd',
                              host='host_name', port=port_num,sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES')
```

This will throw a mysql exception when null values are passed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your `sql_mode` to be more strict. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting

Specifically, I think you're running into:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero